# Moving of a dyamic web project with database

Tags: database, eclipse

I have created a dynamic web project in Eclipse. The project creates a database within it. Testing it on a local machine having Tomcat server works fine. I want to deploy this project with the database to another system running Tomcat. How to accomplish this task? Internet has been of little help to me.

For example a web project Students created. A database with table named StudentsOfStdV created. This database has some data. For testing purposes I want to export the .war file and the database along with it to a different machine running a server. How to do it?

Comment: Database does not go along with .war. You have to create it on first run.

Comment: @HardikMishra This means that the database has to be installed and created manually after the web project has been installed using the .war file?

Comment: Yes, The database server has to be installed.

Comment: @HardikMishra Thanks!!! Will let you know how it goes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to Export War from Eclipse and deploy it on Tomcat.

Read tutorials on

Web application Deployment Guide: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html

How to setup Tomcat: http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/

Export War from eclipse: http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/eclipse/how-to-make-war-file-in-eclipse.html

EDIT:

Database does not go along with `.war`. The database server has to be installed first and then You can create it on first run or manually.

Comment: I get the export of war...But war file does not include the databases information, right? How do I export the database with the war file is my question!!

Comment: @KunalShah: The details you provided in the question is not sufficient to give answer to you question. Still I tried.Please provide more details on "databases information".